# Webpack resolve.modulesDirectories doesn't seem to work

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Webpack is pretty clear that it's resolution is going to work like Node's does. Perhaps I misunderstand it, but it appears to be broken. This is an Angular 2 project.
Here is what I have configured:

```
module.exports = {
    //....
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
        root: helpers.root(), //Root points to the root of my project
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'app/module'],
    },
}
```

Angular modules or components should then be able to import via:

```
import {SomeComponent} from 'common-mdl';
```

with the following structure:

```
-config/
    -webpack.js
-app/
    -module/
        -common-mdl
            -index.ts //Contains export for common-mdl
            -common-mdl.ts //Contains common-mdl module definition
        -other-mdl
            -index.ts //Contains export for other-mdl
            -other-mdl.ts //Contains other-mdl module definition
```

If I try to use the above import statement with the above structure, I get errors with webpack stating that it can't find module 'common-mdl'.

I have also tried setting up aliases, to no avail.

1) Do I misinterpret the module resolution strategy?

2) If I do, what should I do differently?

3) If not, is this a bug?

4) How does Angular achieve the same strategy? Why does `import {Something} from '@angular/core';` work with Angular but not my stuff?

Comment: Did you found the answers on your questions? I have the same right now.

Comment: @FUT Nope, however I did notice that the import system is very picky about ordering of imports (which is annoying since that's half the point of using an import system). I'm just using relative paths for now... I seem to recall this being a logged bug with Webpack but I'm too busy to dig it up right now. If I come across it later I'll try to post it.

Comment: This obstacle can be easily resolved using webpack (in fact ng-cli does that under the hood) using [resolve.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories). But I have no idea where should I place that configuration. I tried to read `angular-cli` and `ember-cli` code and it looks like they are composing final `webpack.config.json` from several sources. I tried to add that config to some of them but that did not work. Looks like I am very close to the solution but can not make the next step. Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone found the answer to the problem ?

Comment: I have noticed that there are some weird quirks around order-of-definition. I can't really give good examples because it seems very inconsistent, but I think this is actually a product of the require system. When in doubt, import the required file directly and that WILL work. Ugly. But... it is what is is for now.